# How to install MongoDB 3.2 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, mongodb

I followed these instructions:

http://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

```
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
$ apt-get install mongodb-org=3.2.0 mongodb-org-server=3.2.0 mongodb-org-shell=3.2.0 mongodb-org-mongos=3.2.0 mongodb-org-tools=3.2.0
```

But I get the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/wily/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/wily/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What could be the cause? And how to install it successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, Feb 7th, 2016, per [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/):

> MongoDB only provides packages for 64-bit long-term
>   support Ubuntu releases. Currently, this means 12.04 LTS (Precise
>   Pangolin) and 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). While the packages may work
>   with other Ubuntu releases, this is not a supported configuration.

You should follow the instructions for [installing MongoDB from a tarball](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/).

In brief:

```
$ curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.1.tgz
$ tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.11.tgz
$ mkdir -p <your-intended-mongodb-install-directory>
$ cp -R -n mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.11/ <your-intended-mongodb-install-directory>
$ export PATH=<your-intended-mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```

Even if you manually download the `.deb` package for 14.04, there is a problem with 15.10 [confirmed here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21880). Either way after manual installation you need to configure MongoDB and either run it as a process or daemonize it using for example:

```
daemon -- <your-intended-mongodb-install-directory>/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```